# kong admin api giving 404 to /services path

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, api-gateway, rancher, kong

I am trying to set up **Kong API gateway** inside the rancher Kubernetes in db mode(PostgreSQL PV) installed through helm with latest version. The admin API that Kong exposes doesn't have the services or routes path available. So calling the API with "**/services**" path is giving **404** error. The root path is giving **200** OK status

1. Calling the `http://localhost:8001` is giving 200 OK status with the following response body:

> curl localhost:8001

response:

```
{
  "paths": [
    "/api",
    "/api/v1",
    "/apis",
    "/apis/",
    "/apis/acme.cert-manager.io",
    "/apis/acme.cert-manager.io/v1",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/apps",
    "/apis/apps/v1",
    "/apis/authentication.k8s.io",
    "/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/authorization.k8s.io",
    "/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/autoscaling",
    "/apis/autoscaling/v1",
    "/apis/autoscaling/v2",
    "/apis/autoscaling/v2beta1",
    "/apis/autoscaling/v2beta2",
    "/apis/batch",
    "/apis/batch/v1",
    "/apis/batch/v1beta1",
    "/apis/catalog.cattle.io",
    "/apis/catalog.cattle.io/v1",
    "/apis/cert-manager.io",
    "/apis/cert-manager.io/v1",
    "/apis/certificates.k8s.io",
    "/apis/certificates.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/cluster.cattle.io",
    "/apis/cluster.cattle.io/v3",
    "/apis/configuration.konghq.com",
    "/apis/configuration.konghq.com/v1",
    "/apis/configuration.konghq.com/v1alpha1",
    "/apis/configuration.konghq.com/v1beta1",
    "/apis/coordination.k8s.io",
    "/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/crd.projectcalico.org",
    "/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1",
    "/apis/discovery.k8s.io",
    "/apis/discovery.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/events.k8s.io",
    "/apis/events.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/events.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io",
    "/apis/flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io/v1beta2",
    "/apis/management.cattle.io",
    "/apis/management.cattle.io/v3",
    "/apis/metallb.io",
    "/apis/metrics.k8s.io",
    "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/networking.k8s.io",
    "/apis/networking.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/node.k8s.io",
    "/apis/node.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/node.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/policy",
    "/apis/policy/v1",
    "/apis/policy/v1beta1",
    "/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io",
    "/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/scheduling.k8s.io",
    "/apis/scheduling.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/storage.k8s.io",
    "/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/ui.cattle.io",
    "/apis/ui.cattle.io/v1",
    "/healthz",
    "/healthz/autoregister-completion",
    "/healthz/etcd",
    "/healthz/log",
    "/healthz/ping",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/aggregator-reload-proxy-client-cert",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/apiservice-openapi-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/apiservice-openapiv3-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/apiservice-registration-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/apiservice-status-available-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/bootstrap-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/crd-informer-synced",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/kube-apiserver-autoregistration",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-config-consumer",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-config-producer",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-filter",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/rbac/bootstrap-roles",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/scheduling/bootstrap-system-priority-classes",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-cluster-authentication-info-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-kube-aggregator-informers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-admission-initializer",
    "/livez",
    "/livez/autoregister-completion",
    "/livez/etcd",
    "/livez/log",
    "/livez/ping",
    "/livez/poststarthook/aggregator-reload-proxy-client-cert",
    "/livez/poststarthook/apiservice-openapi-controller",
    "/livez/poststarthook/apiservice-openapiv3-controller",
    "/livez/poststarthook/apiservice-registration-controller",
    "/livez/poststarthook/apiservice-status-available-controller",
    "/livez/poststarthook/bootstrap-controller",
    "/livez/poststarthook/crd-informer-synced",
    "/livez/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
    "/livez/poststarthook/kube-apiserver-autoregistration",
    "/livez/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-config-consumer",
    "/livez/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-config-producer",
    "/livez/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-filter",
    "/livez/poststarthook/rbac/bootstrap-roles",
    "/livez/poststarthook/scheduling/bootstrap-system-priority-classes",
    "/livez/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers",
    "/livez/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers",
    "/livez/poststarthook/start-cluster-authentication-info-controller",
    "/livez/poststarthook/start-kube-aggregator-informers",
    "/livez/poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-admission-initializer",
    "/logs",
    "/metrics",
    "/openapi/v2",
    "/openapi/v3",
    "/openapi/v3/",
    "/readyz",
    "/readyz/autoregister-completion",
    "/readyz/etcd",
    "/readyz/informer-sync",
    "/readyz/log",
    "/readyz/ping",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/aggregator-reload-proxy-client-cert",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/apiservice-openapi-controller",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/apiservice-openapiv3-controller",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/apiservice-registration-controller",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/apiservice-status-available-controller",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/bootstrap-controller",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/crd-informer-synced",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/kube-apiserver-autoregistration",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-config-consumer",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-config-producer",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-filter",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/rbac/bootstrap-roles",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/scheduling/bootstrap-system-priority-classes",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/start-cluster-authentication-info-controller",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/start-kube-aggregator-informers",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-admission-initializer",
    "/readyz/shutdown",
    "/version"
  ]
```

2. Calling the admin API root path with --head flag:

> curl --head localhost:8001

**response**:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Audit-Id: 68823bl0-9675-413a-8ef6-7th7df4d33z3
> Cache-Control: no-cache, private Content-Type: application/json Date:
> Mon, 20 Feb 2023 06:21:20 GMT X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid:
> bdb1c5f5-5e70-49b0-ba33-cb7420e90d89
> X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid:
> 29u9a7m6-b50j-404d-brg7-7f98b77c1ghb

**3. Calling the admin API with /services path to list all the services:

> curl localhost:8001/services

response:  404 page not found**

Comment: You're hitting the Kubernetes API server, not Kong. Have you got Kong exposed as a service?

Answer (score 0):

Your response is not Kong API Gateway response, please ensure your kong is exposed to public.